# SAP Cloud OData filter logical (substringof and substringof) on same property fails

Tags: filter, odata, sap-cloud-platform

I'm working with the SAP Cloud platform and their OData APIs.
I'm having an OData filter that looks like this:

```
$filter=substringof('120',PROPERTY) and substringof('130',PROPERTY)
```

As soon as I have 2 substringof operations on the **same property name**, the query fails.

```
"Expression can not converted into ABAP select options"
```

Replacing the 'and' with an 'or' passes, but changes completely the context of my query.

My property is defined as a string, that can be either empty, have 1 value, or multiple comma-separated values, and the query should return the items that has all values specified.

```
PROPERTY=""
PROPERTY="120"
PROPERTY="120,130,150"
```

According to this question on the sap forums from 2012, multiple actions on the same properties are not supported yet.
https://answers.sap.com/questions/9264652/multiple-filters-with-dates.html

Can someone confirm this is still the case?
Does someone have another **performant** solution for my case?

Thanks

Comment: what exactly is the problem with using the OR operator? Shouldn't it do exactly what you are trying to do or what is the output you are getting from using the OR operator?

Comment: In my example, the OR will return the last 2 items. With an AND you will only return the last item. An item that has both 120 AND 130 defined in the property.

Comment: So you need only the last one? because in your question it seems like you need both and the OR is doing that right?

Comment: yes, I only need the last one. that's why my original filter uses and between the 2 constraints